# Start chrome via bash from lightdm

Tags: bash, google-chrome, lightdm, kiosk

Im trying to launch a simple chrome kiosk when logging in from lightdm but it keeps returning to the login screen directly after login.

Calling /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc directly from kiosk.desktop works well but I would like to call a bash script to start the kiosk instead of altering the xinitrc.

This works:

```
# /usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Kiosk
Exec=/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
TryExec=/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
Type=Application
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

google-chrome https://google.com --kiosk

. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

But when calling bash script it returns to login screen.
/usr/share/kiosk/start.sh is set as executable.

```
# /usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Kiosk
Exec=/usr/share/kiosk/start.sh
TryExec=/usr/share/kiosk/start.sh
Type=Application
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# /usr/share/kiosk/start.sh
google-chrome https://google.com --kiosk
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a very simple fix.

The bash file was created on windows which caused it not to run. Created it locally and now it runs gin.